# Warning message when session starts

Tags: php, session, warnings

I have configured the `session`, but receiving this warning message.

> PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/domain/public_html/webroot/getstatus.php:56) in
>   /home/domain/public_html/webroot/getstatus.php on line 56, referer:
>   http://www.domain.com/index

On line 56 of `getstatus.php: session_start();`

Please anybody know about this warning message then please reply?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session cookie is sent as part of the response headers, and headers must be sent to the browser before any other content.

Your `session_start()` call is on line 56, either make sure `session_start()` is at the very beginning of your page/script, or make sure that you don't print out any content before line 56.

Answer (score 0):

This message usually means that you have already output something before calling `session_start()`. The `session_start()` function needs to be called before any output.